# Why does my dual-boot system, with separate drives for Ubuntu and Windows, boots directly to Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu on one of my 3 drives. I got one SSD with Windows on it, and then a HDD which I use with the SSD. Now I have installed Ubuntu on the third drive successfully.

When I power on the computer, it instantly boots Windows and when I open the file manager, I can only see the SSD drive and the other HDD (not the Ubuntu one). Only seeing these drives is what I want (I think?), but I want to be able to choose to boot either Ubuntu or Windows every time I power on the computer.

I tried going into the boot menu and somehow change the boot order, but I ran into a problem I think. It seems as if Windows is "UEFI" and Ubuntu "Hard disk". I will provide some pictures below to help you out, as I'm not that tech-savvy as you may understand.

So, essentially, this boils down to: How do I change the boot order to be able to choose which one to boot every time I power on the PC, and is there a problem that Windows says "UEFI" and Ubuntu "Hard disk"?

Here are some relevant pictures:

[image: Sata3 is Ubuntu]

[image: #1 is Windows and #7 is Ubuntu, I think]

[image: UEFI Hard Disk Drive BBS Priorities]

[image: Hard Disk Drive BBS Priorities]

Thank you very much if you've spent your time on this problem!

Comment: Windows is installed as a UEFI operating system and so should Ubuntu. Did you install Ubuntu in compatibility mode (MBR) instead?  Your boot priority needs to have Ubuntu first if you want to use GRUB

Comment: hm I don't really know, where is it that I make that choice? I downloaded ubuntu LTS and used Rufus to burn it (?) onto my flash drive.

Comment: It's determined by how you flash and/or boot the installation media. If you boot into compatibility mode your installation will be in compatibility mode. Similarly if your installation media is BIOS/MBR/compatibility mode you won't be able to boot UEFI and won't be able to install UEFI.  You should do more research about your motherboard about how to boot UEFI.  You might also want to use balena etcher to flash the installation media.  If it's flashed with etcher, you can boot either BIOS or UEFI

Comment: Okey thank you very much!

Comment: I have successfully installed it with UEFI. Now it instead auto boot to Ubuntu, how would I go about to learn how to change that?

Comment: UEFI should show both Windows & Ubuntu as boot options. And if both UEFI, grub should show both Ubuntu as default, but Windows as an option. If not shown in grub run this: `sudo update-grub` which just updates grub menu with all installed systems in same boot mode as grub/Ubuntu.

Comment: Per what @oldfred commented, as long as GRUB has entries for both operating systems, when you boot to the volume with Ubuntu, the GRUB menu will appear and allow you to choose the operating system.

Comment: Thanks guys, It is working now. Now when I woke up it just showed the GRUB interface for a sec then booted automatically to Ubuntu. I used some repair tool, and it is working again :)